# C# and WPF : simple 2D area for basic drawing

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

Using JavaFX, I created a class which inherits `Canvas` and reimplemented the `update()` method to get a `GraphicsContext2D`, with which I could use simple drawing primitives like `strokeLine()`, `fillArc()`, `fillOval()`, etc.

What would be the equivalent in C# using WPF ?

Comment: Just add some shape objects to the Children collection of a Canvas. No need to derive from Canvas. There is Line, Polyline, Ellipse, Rectangle, Path etc. See [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:~:text=%20Shapes%20and%20Basic%20Drawing%20in%20WPF%20Overview,Stroke%20and%20Fill.%20In%20the%20following...%20More%20)

Answer (score 0):

In wpf there is also Canvas from which you can inherit and implement your addition logic. Also wpf has InkCanvas with some default implementation which you can also extend. Look at https://github.com/antfu/live-draw for example with InkCanvas.